# mongodb index is created but is not used during query

Tags: mongodb

Hope this is not a totally stupid question.
I'm creating a compound index on mongodb on fields that contain strings.
After running the index creation I do not see a process that creates the index via db.currentOp(), But I do see the index if I run getIndexes().

```
db.sampledb.createIndex(
    {
        "DevIdent.ParametersExt. ID": 1,
        "DevIdent.Parameters.Type": 1,
        "MetaData.SessionName": 1
    },
    {
        background: false,
        name: "sample",
    }
)
```

Running this query with explain I always get COLLSCAN I never see an index scan instead of COLLSCAN:

```
db.sampledb.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "DevIdent.ParametersExt.ID": { "$regex": ".*22~44.*" },
            "DevIdent.Parameters.Type": { "$ne": "TYPICAL" },
            "MetaData.SessionName": "2021_02_09_13_31_03"
        }
    }
])
```

am I missing something basic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index can be used only for "prefixed" `^....` regexps. I find the documentation at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use is pretty clear about it so I will just quote it here:

> For case sensitive regular expression queries, if an index exists for
> the field, then MongoDB matches the regular expression against the
> values in the index, which can be faster than a collection scan.
> Further optimization can occur if the regular expression is a “prefix
> expression”, which means that all potential matches start with the
> same string. This allows MongoDB to construct a “range” from that
> prefix and only match against those values from the index that fall
> within that range.
>
> A regular expression is a “prefix expression” if it starts with a
> caret (^) or a left anchor (\A), followed by a string of simple
> symbols. For example, the regex /^abc.*/ will be optimized by matching
> only against the values from the index that start with abc.
>
> Additionally, while /^a/, /^a.*/, and /^a.*$/ match equivalent
> strings, they have different performance characteristics. All of these
> expressions use an index if an appropriate index exists; however,
> /^a.*/, and /^a.*$/ are slower. /^a/ can stop scanning after matching
> the prefix.

Comment: This is correct, but note that had the OP put the regex field _last_ in the index, Mongo could still have used this multi-column index by just choosing to scan after filtering on the first two fields.  So, the index _could_ have been used, if phrased differently.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `DevIdent.ParametersExt. ID` looks first to me at current edition of the question. I totally agree that if it was the last in the index definition the index could be used. Assuming the space is a typo in the question of course.

Comment: Yep the space was just a copy mistake to stackoverflow as I changed the name of the field to be shorter for the question to be less confusing and ended up causing more confusion , sorry for that

Comment: I didn’t come across the regex prefix issue in the documentation before , thank you for pointing it out it was a great help

Answer (score 2):

This matching filter is the problem:

```
"DevIdent.ParametersExt.ID": { "$regex": ".*22~44.*" }
```

You are searching for the text `22~44` *anywhere* in the `DevIdent.ParametersExt.ID` field.  The problem is that a B-tree based index can only be used if searching can start at the very beginning of the field, which is not the case here.

However, there is no reason why the index could not be used on the other two fields.  But, since you started your multi-column index on a field which can't be used, therefore Mongo is choosing to just not use this index at all.

You could consider just defining an index on the other two fields:

```js
db.sampledb.createIndex({
    "DevIdent.Parameters.Type": 1,
    "MetaData.SessionName": 1
},
{
    background:false,
    name: "sample",
});
```

Assuming that these two fields have high cardinality (i.e. they are very restrictive), then Mongo may choose to use the index, despite the regex condition on the third field.

Comment: I didn’t come across the regex prefix issue in the documentation before , thank you for pointing it out it was a great help!!

Answer (score 1):

Whatever everyone has posted as an answer holds true for inefficient use of index, but it still should come across as IXSCAN in explain plan, therefore I did a test.

```
db.sampledb.createIndex(
    {
        "DevIdent.ParametersExt. ID": 1,
        "DevIdent.Parameters.Type": 1,
        "MetaData.SessionName": 1
    },
    {
        background: false,
        name: "sample",
    }
)
```

This is your command there is some space between `DevIdent.ParametersExt. & ID`, which is causing an issue but you still won't be able to create a new index without the space, gives duplicate error. Remove this index all together and create a new one without the space.

> EDIT : Schoolkid mistake, remove the name part, you should be able to
> create both the indexes, in the tree it is simply field name which is
> a string being stored with respective BSON types, therefore with the
> space and without it are two indexes separately.

```
db.sampledb.createIndex(
    {
        "DevIdent.ParametersExt.ID": 1,
        "DevIdent.Parameters.Type": 1,
        "MetaData.SessionName": 1
    },
    {
        background: false,
        name: "sample",
    }
)
```

Try your aggregate command now, works for me.

```
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "test_content.test4",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [ 
            {
                "MetaData.SessionName" : {
                    "$eq" : "2021_02_09_13_31_03"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "DevIdent.ParametersExt.ID" : {
                    "$regex" : ".*22~44.*"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "DevIdent.Parameters.Type" : {
                    "$not" : {
                        "$eq" : "TYPICAL"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "optimizedPipeline" : true,
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "DevIdent.ParametersExt.ID" : {
                    "$regex" : ".*22~44.*"
                }
            },
            "keyPattern" : {
                "DevIdent.ParametersExt.ID" : 1.0,
                "DevIdent.Parameters.Type" : 1.0,
                "MetaData.SessionName" : 1.0
            },
            "indexName" : "sample",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                "DevIdent.ParametersExt.ID" : [],
                "DevIdent.Parameters.Type" : [],
                "MetaData.SessionName" : []
            },
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 2,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "DevIdent.ParametersExt.ID" : [ 
                    "[\"\", {})", 
                    "[/.*22~44.*/, /.*22~44.*/]"
                ],
                "DevIdent.Parameters.Type" : [ 
                    "[MinKey, \"TYPICAL\")", 
                    "(\"TYPICAL\", MaxKey]"
                ],
                "MetaData.SessionName" : [ 
                    "[\"2021_02_09_13_31_03\", \"2021_02_09_13_31_03\"]"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: You are totally correct due to the fact that the index was created on a different collection it did not work but the next problem that I encountered was the regex issue , so we need to redesign the data to show up at the start of the field for efficient indexing , at the end everyone were correct and really helpful , many thanks !

Comment: @AnatolyZaretsky If you don't mind accept the correct answer, mark it basically.